# Alamofire error after Swift 3.0 migration: "Cannot convert value of type '(URL, HTTPURLResponse)-> (URL)' to expected argument type 'Parameters'"?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am currently in the process of updating my codebase to Swift 3.0., and I am using Alamofire.  I had to update Alamofire to 4.0 ([Alamofire git repo](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)).  I have a method to download media (video), and before migration it worked wonderfully.  After using Xcode's migration tool I ended up with this error: "Cannot convert value of type '(URL, HTTPURLResponse)-> (URL)' to expected argument type 'Parameters?', which is a [String: Any].  What exactly is this Parameters object and why is it throwing an error? The only difference between this code before migration and now is that now NSURL is replaced by URL. Any help would be wonderful, as I have been stuck on this for the past 3 hours.

```
let mediaSourceURI: String = media.sourceURI
var filePath: URL?
let destination: (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> (URL) = {
    (temporaryURL, response) in

    if let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first, let suggestedFilename = response.suggestedFilename {
        filePath = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(suggestedFilename)")
        return filePath!
    }
    return temporaryURL
}

//ERROR BELOW:  "destination" is highlighted, and says "Cannot convert value of type '(URL, HTTPURLResponse)-> (URL)' to expected argument type 'Parameters?"
RequestManager.mediaDownloadAlamofireManager.download(mediaSourceURI, method: .get, parameters: destination).response {
    (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

    self.completeOperation()

}
```

Here is a link I have been trying to use for reference: [Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol), particularly in the Parameter Encoding Protocol section.

Here is the syntax of the updated download method in Alamofire:
[image]

//mediaDownloadAlamofireManager code, which has no errors:

```
static let mediaDownloadAlamofireManager: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [baseURL : .disableEvaluation]
    let manager = SessionManager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
    return manager
}()
```

Comment: The parameters you are referring to expects the type `[String: Any]`, but yours is `(URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> (URL)`. However, what is your RequestManager? Did you define that?

Comment: The RequestManager is "mediaDownloadAlamofireManager ", a SessionManager, and is defined globally in another file.  And yes, the download method I am using is most likely outdated, I've tried with that method you mentioned and I'm still not creating my "parameter" right.  Im not quite sure how to convert my destination to [String: Any]

Comment: Maybe this helps: An example for a parameter would be `let exampleParameters = ["search": "bob"]`, then the call in Alamofire would be something along: `Alamofire.download(mediaSourceURI, method: .get, parameters: exampleParameters)` or in your case `RequestManager.mediaDownloadAlamofireManager.download(mediaSourceURI, method: .get, parameters: exampleParameters)`

Comment: Ah I know the problem. Just use your initial code and replace in `.download(mediaSourceURI, method: .get, parameters: destination)`  the word parameter with destination, so it looks like `.download(mediaSourceURI, method: .get, destination: destination)`. Must be a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Simple Typo

> RequestManager.mediaDownloadAlamofireManager.download(mediaSourceURI,
> method: .get, **parameters**: destination)

with

> RequestManager.mediaDownloadAlamofireManager.download(mediaSourceURI,
> method: .get, **destination**: destination)

---

## 2. Change in DownloadFileDestination-Type

Alamofire 4.0 [changed the type](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#download-options)  of `DownloadFileDestination` – the parameter that you call **destination**. It changed from:

> (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> (URL)

to

> (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> (URL, DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions)

So you also need to change your method to something like this:

```
let destination: (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> (URL, DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions) = {
    (temporaryURL, response) in
        
    if let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first, let suggestedFilename = response.suggestedFilename {
        filePath = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(suggestedFilename)")
        return (filePath!, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
    return (temporaryURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}
```

Please note that you no longer just return the url, but also have [more control over how Alamofire stores files on the file system](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#download-options). Just specify the options you want, such as *removePreviousFile* or/and *createIntermediateDirectories*. They are now returned as a [Tuple](https://www.weheartswift.com/tuples-enums/).

Comment: I just tried, its still generating an error: "Incorrect argument label in call (have '_:method:destination:', expected '_:method:parameters:').  Thanks for helping me out by the way.

Comment: how does the method `mediaDownloadAlamofireManager` look like? I assume you defined it to interface with Alamofire? I assume you also need to update that one.

Comment: I've edited my question w/ the mediaDownloadAlamofireManager code

Comment: @JoshO'Connor I noticed that they changed the DownloadFileDestination-type in 4.0. Please review my updated answer.